# Specific regex query

Tags: regex

I have searched the regex answers and none seem to address this query I have. I'm using a specific regex product that can search through text and discard a specific part of a line in an email message.

In this instance, I have a line that I can search through with Regex and it discards 'Subject: '

I need to then;

1. Discard the second part of the field
2. Then Select the actual text (Which is then passed to a seperate process)

---

For instance, this check (for another test I have written) gets the 'ThisServer Blah blah' text- which is passed to the next part of the process, discards the 'Subject: ' (Which is automatic) and discards the 'Alert Open';

```
(?:Alert open: ([^\n\r]*))
```

Subject: Alert Open: **ThisServer Blah blah**

So, that all works and ThisServer Blah blah is passed to the next part..

---

I have a new case I'm trying to write for;

Subject: This Thing is having Problems

1. 'Subject: ' is automatically discarded, so there is no need to worry about it
2. I want to specifically discard ' is having problems'

which leaves..

3. '**This Thing**' is passed to the next stage.

---

`((?: is having problems))`   - Discards the ' is having problems'. Subject: is already taken care of, but I need to SELECT the '**This Thing**' so that it can be passed to the next part, but can't work out how to do it..

Comment: We need more context : which language is it for?

Comment: It's the regex field processor used in JEMH (Which is used in JIRA)

Comment: Hi - thanks for the answer, I should have specified that I don't know what 'This Thing' is - it would change every time.. so we might have Subject: This Thing is having problems, then Subject: This other thing is having problems, then Subject: Something else is having problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've managed to solve it myself - like all these things, it was a lot easier than I thought...

Firstly, I didn't check on the Subject: line (I checked the whole email)

Then for the line;

Subject: This-server is having problems

Subject: Now gives me a place to start, so the following works;

```
(?:Subject: )([^\n\r]*)(?: is having problems)
```

The key was having a place to start. This excludes the first bit (Subject:) then excludes the second bit ( is having problems) and then places the result into group 1 (I removed the extra brackets to force the correct group)

Answer (score 0):

In field mapping, add a mapping that look into the subject (or body if relevant) that looks for `Subject: (.*?) is having Problems` and put it in the field you want to assign. See [this image](https://media-api.atlassian.io/file/a791be2f-652d-4ad1-9546-2729595a0761/image?mode=full-fit&client=617d3744-28c7-4d2c-94ae-a724e1be4a7f&token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiI2MTdkMzc0NC0yOGM3LTRkMmMtOTRhZS1hNzI0ZTFiZTRhN2YiLCJhY2Nlc3MiOnsidXJuOmZpbGVzdG9yZTpmaWxlOmE3OTFiZTJmLTY1MmQtNGFkMS05NTQ2LTI3Mjk1OTVhMDc2MSI6WyJyZWFkIl19LCJleHAiOjE1MDEwNjY1ODcsIm5iZiI6MTUwMTA2MzIyN30.uZC-MiY4VV3cUBwjRDmyeEzKT0bWQ8dzJhxm-aiHtjY) that might help

Comment: Subject: Is automatically discarded by JIRA/JEMH. It's getting that middle bit that is used in JEMH to then do a seperate search outside the Regex that I need to get - so you need to discard what you don't want and the select what you do want - which is then passed onto the second part (Which performs a match on existing JIRA Tickets)